# Which SIM card to use in Budapest?

Tags: cellphones, hungary

I am travelling to Budapest from India for a week.

Which SIM card should I get ?

What is the process for getting a sim card for a traveler and where can I find it ?

Comment: If you just would like to use internet (no phone calls) then not really to need buying sim card. Just use free local wifi hot-spots ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepaid plans are available, and they work as usual - you show up in a store, buy a SIM card (passport was not needed), load some money into it, and choose a plan. There are many providers and many plans, the store will ask you what your usage pattern would be (mostly use Internet? Call India? Receive local calls?) and will suggest a few plans depending on what you need and on what they sell. Expect to spend around $15 at least.